# Build fails if $file_name is non-latin

Tags: sublime-text-2

I'm using Windows version of Sublime Text 2 and [MultiMarkdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/) as a build system. It works fine unless target file name has Cyrillic characters in it. Then it fails silently.

To test this I'm using following build config.

```
{
   "cmd": ["echo", "$file_name", ">C:\\1.txt"],
     "selector": "text.html.markdown",
     "shell": true
}
```

How do I build a file with name like `Идеи.md`?